# Why does my mesh rotate face down when i delete my bone?

Tags: mesh, rigging, transforms, bones

Ok so, I got this bone that I wanted to get rid of so I can start over with fresh new ones.
The bones were once weighted with my legs mesh but then I deleted them.

So when ever I delete the bones my entire leg mesh just turns face down and move a little out of place.

Why is it doing this? it's kind of annoying.

Here's what I mean.

That's how it looks totally normal.

[image]

This is how it looks all wonky and crap..

[image]

I'd appreciate it if some gave me a hand. Idk if this is like some sort of bug, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the bone you are deleting is not the parent to any other bone, because if that is the case their parent would become NULL and the tranformation they were inheriting will become garbage (or maybe just 0 in Blender).
So make sure you undo parenting prior to deletion.

Comment: Mhm, my upper leg mesh is parented to my upper leg bone. Should I remove that 1st then delete my bone?

Comment: alright ncm. Did as you instructed and it turned out fine. Hopefully it doesn't mess up. I have a knack for coming across issues lol. 

I think the reason why I thought something was wrong because, I didn't remove the full parent, I just removed the bone. But now I removed the full parent such as my armature and it's alright.

Comment: No worries, good luck with the project :)

Comment: Thank you. I have big dreams. I hope to come far with Blender. 3D modeling is awesome.